# How to update airflow.cfg file in MWAA local Runner

Tags: docker, airflow, mwaa

I need to update the airflow configuration file (usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg) in my Docker image running MWAA-Local-Runner.

However, the changes I do when editing the file from my host computer are not reflected when restarting the environment using  ./mwaa-local-env start command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .env file (for example .env.localrunner) and set variable via airflow env varaibles convention (AIRFLOW__SECTION__VARIABLE)

for example if I want to change the webserver instance_name to "DEV" i can add the following to my .env.localrunner file

```
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__INSTANCE_NAME=DEV
```

or if you need to set AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS you can :

> AIRFLOW__SECRETS__BACKEND_KWARGS={"connections_prefix": "airflow/connections", "region_name": "aws_region"}

in the docker-compose that you run your local-mwaa add the following under local-runner in order to read those variables.

```
    env_file:
  - .env.localrunner
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. These avariables will be taken into consideration when I run docker-compose -up or do I hav to rebuild the image everytime I adjust them ? Some variables like secrets/backend_kwards are dictionary, (example: backend_kwargs = {"connections_prefix": "/airflow/connections", "variables_prefix" : "airflow/variables"}). Wil these vriables be interpreted correctly as-is ?

Comment: On docker compose up. No need to rebuild image

Comment: also, you can set dict in the value. added an example in my answer

Comment: thank you very much for your help. It works. I accepted your answer.